# How to count reaction Discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a poll command in `discord.js`, but I'm not sure how I can get the amount of people who reacted to a specific emoji. This is my code:

```js
if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('You need to ask a question.');
let pollq = args.join(' ');
let whoask = msg.author.username;

const poll = new D.MessageEmbed()
 .setTitle('New Poll')
 .setAuthor(
  'Cleansound',
  'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxJ8Qab93CDlxO7tOg06Jifb1Z1-14j1Xj2nt3dNg=s100-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo'
 )
 .setDescription(`${whoask} Baru Saja Membuat Pollin question baru`)
 .setDescription(`${pollq}`)
 .addField(`  `, 'Untuk Setuju')
 .addField(`  `, 'Untuk Tidak Setuju')
 .setTimestamp()
 .setFooter(
  'Cleansound Host',
  'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxJ8Qab93CDlxO7tOg06Jifb1Z1-14j1Xj2nt3dNg=s100-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo'
 );
await poll.react('');
await poll.react('');
msg.channel.send(poll);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`Message.reactions.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reactions), which will return a collection of every [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) on that message. From there, you can use [`Collection#get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) to fetch your preferred reaction, and use the [`MessageReaction#count`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=count) to see how many people have reacted to it.

```js
poll.reactions.cache.get('').count;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Still works as of Discord.js v14.0.3